# How to get data or value from any div in php

Tags: php, html, css

i Have create php page where use many div with different id name.
so i want to get data or value from one div.
Here am showing one div with id name 
i want to get data or value from this div.

```
<div id="tablename">tablename</div>
```

i have use this but its not working.

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$thediv = $doc->getElementById('tablename');
echo $thediv->textContent;
```

So please tell me how can i get this value from my div?

Comment: r u sure that each div having unique id?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here you find something useful on [ask]. Try to be as detailed as possible, for example, what do you mean with "not working" ( an error, an unexpected result, ...) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the whole content of your page to the class, otherwise, it can't select nothing since it thinks the document is empty:

```
$content = '<div id="tablename"></div>';
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content); // That's the addition
$thediv = $doc->getElementById('tablename');
echo $thediv->textContent;
```

More info:

- [loadHTML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php): Load the HTML from a string.
- [loadHTMLFile()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php): Load the HTML from a file.

Comment: can you tell me how can add that code in smarty .if you have any idea can you please share

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded and include PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser from https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/ and

Try this

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html("http://www.facebook.com");
$displaybody = $html->find('div[id=blueBarDOMInspector]', 0)->plaintext;
echo $displaybody ;exit;
```

Comment: He is using `DomDocument`, why should change to another library? That's not useful, even the same result will shown